# Feritztrainer on Mac, Install conflict

Tags: chessbase

I have installed 3 Fritztrainers on the Mac, with the native Mac program included in the modern Fritztrainers.

After having activated and used them without problems, starting a second one of the Fritztrainers causes the activation to be requested again.

It seems that after installing 2 or more Fritztrainers, they all conflict. with only 1 Fritztrainer installed the problem does not occur.

Does anyone have the same problem and have they solved it?

Comment: Have you already tried to contact the official ChessBase support about this?